# Can't find MySQL on Jupyter Notebooks, Conda Environment, Python 3.6

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to consume a MySQL database from a jupyter notebook, from a conda environment that I created.

My firsts tries did not work, which here:

- using `sqlalchemy`
- using `mysql-connector-python`
- using `pymysql`

I've tried installing them, some of them using `conda install`, some of them using `pip`, always with the environment that I have activated, from which I also initiate my jupyter notebook instance.

The behavior I get is always the same: after installing the packages, I can run an interactive `python` session and in it, I can correctly import the packages and use them, even get results from the database. But when I do it from the notebook, **none of the modules are found**, and that's where I'm stuck.

Some old posts I saw mentioned that they are not available for Python 3.x or for Windows, or for 64 bit systems, but those answers are circa 2016 so they're updated, and the conda description of the packages claim they work correctly in my Windows 10, x64, python=3.6 environment (or so I interpreted).

Environment:

- Windows 10, 64 bit
- python=3.6
- `conda list`:

  ```
  backcall                  0.1.0                     <pip>
  certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0
  colorama                  0.3.9                     <pip>
  decorator                 4.3.0                     <pip>
  ipython                   6.3.1                     <pip>
  ipython-genutils          0.2.0                     <pip>
  jedi                      0.12.0                    <pip>
  mysql-connector-python    2.0.4                    py36_0
  mysqlclient               1.3.12                    <pip>
  parso                     0.2.0                     <pip>
  pickleshare               0.7.4                     <pip>
  pip                       9.0.3                    py36_0
  prettytable               0.7.2                     <pip>
  prompt-toolkit            1.0.15                    <pip>
  Pygments                  2.2.0                     <pip>
  python                    3.6.5                h0c2934d_0
  setuptools                39.0.1                   py36_0
  simplegeneric             0.8.1                     <pip>
  six                       1.11.0                    <pip>
  SQLAlchemy                1.2.7                     <pip>
  sqlparse                  0.2.4                     <pip>
  traitlets                 4.3.2                     <pip>
  vc                        14                   h0510ff6_3
  vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    3
  wcwidth                   0.1.7                     <pip>
  wheel                     0.31.0                   py36_0
  wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
  ```

(Some of the mysql packages are not present because after my failed attempts, I removed them.)

**How do I get the notebooks to find the modules so I can connect to MySQL?**

Comment: have you created an environment within conda?

Comment: @hisi Yes. `conda create -n myEnvName python=3.6`. Note that I did not include the anaconda default packages on purpose.

Comment: did you activate the env before installing packages?

Comment: @hisi Yes, yes I did. Everything here is under the activated environment, as I don't want to modify my global configurations.

Comment: try to look here https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2359

Comment: @Chris That hit the spot. I'll be documenting details soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the link provided by Chris on the comments I was able to figure it out. (Thank you very much!)

The first step was verifying that jupyter is looking for notebooks in the same place where the environment is installing them. A simple approach to this is:

On the console:

```
activate myEnv
python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\myUser\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myEnv\\python.exe'
```

Inside jupyter:

```
import sys
sys.executable

'C:\\Users\\myUser\\Anaconda3\\python.exe'
```

As you can see, jupyter in this case is operating **outside** of the environment, and that's why it is not finding the installed packages.

But then -- why would this happen? I was activating the environment before starting up jupyter. Is it possible I might be, inadvertedly, running a wrong version of Jupyter?

```
where jupyter
C:\Users\myUser\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe
```

Ah -- I'm running a wrong version of jupyter. That must be because **I don't have jupyter installed *in* the environment**.

```
conda install jupyter
# ... installation process ...

where jupyter
C:\Users\myUser\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\Scripts\jupyter.exe
C:\Users\myUser\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe
```

So now, the environment jupyter executable should take precedence. After executing jupyter, the behavior is as expected, and `sys.executable` returns the expected path.